# Hierarchical Tree from Structured Array of Dependent Elements

Tags: javascript, recursion, tree, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

I am looking for an efficient approach to build a tree from the following data structure in JavaScript. Each entry always has length 5 and there never exists any gaps (i.e. nulls) between the entries.

```
var geographies = [
    [ 'Denmark', 'Midtjylland', null, null, null ],
    [ 'Denmark', 'Syddanmark', 'Langeland', null, null ],
    [ 'Denmark', 'Syddanmark', 'Ærø', null, null ],
    [ 'Japan', 'Okinawa', 'Izenajima', null, null ],
    [ 'Japan', 'Hokkaido', 'Rishiri', 'Rishiri-to', null ]
]
```

The desired output should look like this:

```
[{
    label: "Denmark",
    children: [{
            label: "Midtjylland",
        },
        {
            label: "Syddanmark",
            children: [{
                label: "Langeland"
            },
            {
                label: "Ærø"
            }]
        }
    ]
}, {
    label: "Japan",
    children: [{
        label: "Okinawa",
        children: [{
            label: "Izenajima"
        }]
    }, {
        label: "Hokkaido",
        children: [{
            label: "Rishiri",
            children: [{
                label: 'Rishiri-to'
            }]
        }]
    }]
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group the arrays on the first element of each subarray, and then call `to_tree` to the grouped arrays if they are not empty:

```js
function to_tree(d){
   var c = {}
   for (var i of d){
       var k = i.shift();
       c[k] = k in c ? [...c[k], i] : [i]
   }
   return Object.keys(c).map(function(x){return {label:x, ...(c[x].filter(j => j.length).length ? {children:to_tree(c[x].filter(j => j.length))} : {})}})
}
var geographies = [[ 'Denmark', 'Midtjylland', null, null, null ], [ 'Denmark', 'Syddanmark', 'Langeland', null, null ], [ 'Denmark', 'Syddanmark', 'Ærø', null, null ], [ 'Japan', 'Okinawa', 'Izenajima', null, null ], [ 'Japan', 'Hokkaido', 'Rishiri', 'Rishiri-to', null ]]
var geographies1 = [[ 'Greece', null, null, null, null ], [ 'Greece', 'Ionian Islands', 'Lefkada', null, null ], [ 'Greece', 'Attica', 'Salamis', null, null ], [ 'Greece', 'Ionian Islands', 'Cephalonia', null, null ], [ 'Greece', 'Thessaly', 'Skiathos', null, null ], [ 'Greece', 'South Aegean', 'Kea', null, null ], [ 'Greece', 'Attica', 'Kythira', null, null ]]
var r = to_tree(geographies.map(x => x.filter(y => y != null)));
var r1 = to_tree(geographies1.map(x => x.filter(y => y != null)));
console.log(r)
console.log(r1)
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "label": "Denmark",
    "children": [
      {
        "label": "Midtjylland"
      },
      {
        "label": "Syddanmark",
        "children": [
          {
            "label": "Langeland"
          },
          {
            "label": "Ærø"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "label": "Japan",
    "children": [
      {
        "label": "Okinawa",
        "children": [
          {
            "label": "Izenajima"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "label": "Hokkaido",
        "children": [
          {
            "label": "Rishiri",
            "children": [
              {
                "label": "Rishiri-to"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

```
[
  {
    "label": "Greece",
    "children": [
      {
        "label": "Ionian Islands",
        "children": [
          {
            "label": "Lefkada"
          },
          {
            "label": "Cephalonia"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "label": "Attica",
        "children": [
          {
            "label": "Salamis"
          },
          {
            "label": "Kythira"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "label": "Thessaly",
        "children": [
          {
            "label": "Skiathos"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "label": "South Aegean",
        "children": [
          {
            "label": "Kea"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, but I would consider it for a code-only answer.  ("you can use recursion" is not an explanation.)

Comment: It looks better to me.  I tend toward more text-heavy answers, even if there's a lot of code.  As I said, I wasn't the downvoter, but I will try to cancel it out!

Comment: @ScottSauyet Thank you. I think the explanation I added should be helpful to other readers. The recursive pattern of group on leading subarray values, and then applying the recursion to the grouped subarrays is commonly used here on SO for problems such as this, so I would not say my solution is overly novel :)

Comment: Greetings @Ajax1234 - many thank you's. There is one case where this won't work from what I can tell  so far, i.e. `var geographies = [[ 'Greece', null, null, null, null ], [ 'Greece', 'Ionian Islands', 'Lefkada', null, null ], [ 'Greece', 'Attica', 'Salamis', null, null ], [ 'Greece', 'Ionian Islands', 'Cephalonia', null, null ], [ 'Greece', 'Thessaly', 'Skiathos', null, null ], [ 'Greece', 'South Aegean', 'Kea', null, null ], [ 'Greece', 'Attica', 'Kythira', null, null ]]` - this will yield just one element in the tree - happy to accept your answer if it can deal with this situation also

Comment: I see the same behaviour for other levels `var geographies = [[ 'Denmark', 'Syddanmark', 'Langeland', null, null ], [ 'Denmark', 'Syddanmark', null, null, null ], [ 'Denmark', 'Syddanmark', 'Ærø', null, null ], [ 'Japan', 'Okinawa', 'Izenajima', null, null ], [ 'Japan', 'Hokkaido', 'Rishiri', 'Rishiri-to', null ]]` would you suggest I pre-process the geographies list before feeding it to the `to_tree` function?

Comment: @TimothyDalton Please see my recent edit, I made a slight update based on the overall structure of `var geographies = [[ 'Greece', null, null, null, null ], ...]`

Comment: Thank you, this does work now @Ajax1234 !

Comment: @TimothyDalton You are welcome! Glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

This version does a double conversion, first recursively nesting your data in this form:

```json
{
    "Denmark": {
        "Midtjylland": {},
        "Syddanmark": {
            "Langeland": {},
            "Ærø": {}
        }
    },
    "Japan": {
        "Okinawa": {
            "Izenajima": {}
        },
        "Hokkaido": {
            "Rishiri": {
                "Rishiri-to": {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then recursively converting that into your requested output.

There is no fundamental reason that this cannot be done in one go.  But I often find the need for something like that intermediate format, and hence have the tools laying around to do that conversion.  And from there the final conversion is quite simple.

```js
// utility functions
const setPath = ([p, ...ps]) => (v) => (o) =>
  p == undefined ? v : Object .assign (
    Array .isArray (o) || Number .isInteger (p) ? [] : {},
    {...o, [p]: setPath (ps) (v) ((o || {}) [p])}
  )

const nest = (xs) =>
  xs .reduce ((o, p) => setPath (p .filter (Boolean)) ({}) (o), {})


// helper function
const toObjectTree = (o) =>
  Object .entries (o) .map (([name, kids]) => ({
    label: name,
    ...(Object .keys (kids) .length ? {children: toObjectTree (kids)} : {})
  }))


// main function
const convert = (xs) => 
  toObjectTree (nest (xs))


// sample data
const geographies1 = [['Denmark', 'Midtjylland', null, null, null], ['Denmark', 'Syddanmark', 'Langeland', null, null], ['Denmark', 'Syddanmark', 'Ærø', null, null], ['Japan', 'Okinawa', 'Izenajima', null, null], ['Japan', 'Hokkaido', 'Rishiri', 'Rishiri-to', null]]
const geographies2 = [[ 'Greece', null, null, null, null ], [ 'Greece', 'Ionian Islands', 'Lefkada', null, null ], [ 'Greece', 'Attica', 'Salamis', null, null ], [ 'Greece', 'Ionian Islands', 'Cephalonia', null, null ], [ 'Greece', 'Thessaly', 'Skiathos', null, null ], [ 'Greece', 'South Aegean', 'Kea', null, null ], [ 'Greece', 'Attica', 'Kythira', null, null ]]
const geographies3 = [[ 'Denmark', 'Syddanmark', 'Langeland', null, null ], [ 'Denmark', 'Syddanmark', null, null, null ], [ 'Denmark', 'Syddanmark', 'Ærø', null, null ], [ 'Japan', 'Okinawa', 'Izenajima', null, null ], [ 'Japan', 'Hokkaido', 'Rishiri', 'Rishiri-to', null ]]


// demo
console .log (convert (geographies1))
console .log (convert (geographies2))
console .log (convert (geographies3))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We start with the utility function **`setPath`**, which you can find described in more detail in some of my [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a1243641%20setPath).  Briefly, though, it uses an array of strings and/or integers to set the value along a nested path in (a copy of) the object supplied.

Then **`nest`** builds up an object from an array of such paths, with the leaf nodes being empty objects.

We write a helper function **`toObjectTree`** to recursively convert that into your `label`/`children` structure.

And finally the main function **`convert`**, composes `toObjectTree` and `nest` to perform the full transformation.

Note that your fixed-length arrays padded with `null`s is not necessary here.  It works with them by simply filtering out any nulls.  (`filter (Boolean)` is simple enough, but if those paths could be falsey -- perhaps empty strings -- then we'd have to replace this with `filter (x => x!= null)` or some such.)  While this makes it more generic than your request, it should still work for your data.

---

To me, this is a very powerful way of transforming data: take multiple steps, each converting the previous one into a useful intermediate format that progresses toward your final goal, and then simply piping the data through this series of simpler transformations.

Comment: Hi @Scott - thank you for your very detailed answer. By the time I saw this I had already studied the first to try to understand. To be fair to Ajax, I have accepted his approach as I have implemented it in my solution, however your way of explaining is highly commendable.

Comment: Most of those who've been around a while here are doing it because they find the problems enjoyable.  I certainly don't chase rating points or whatever they're called.  I'm glad you appreciate my answer.